# Advice on creating combobox on customcontrol with data binding from different source

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on a user interface for laying out graph (nodes and edges) for setting routes for mobile robot. The code is based on Ashley Davis's NetworkView on codeproject: (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a)

I have created a viewmodel that receives the node types from a database and would like for the customcontrol- NodePropertyEditor to display a dropdown box showing the current type of node the user selected instead of just the name of the type (a property in nodemodel.cs). My question is how do I do that given the current databinding is to the model and only the viewmodel contains the types of nodes

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NaviNodeModel}">
    <customControl:NodePropertyEditor/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The aim is to allow the user to change the node type.

Answer (score 0):

You can databind to your current view model using `ElementName` and `Path` together:

1. Name the root element of your view (probably a UserControl) `root`.
2. Update your binding:

   ```
   <DataTemplate Type="Something">
       <Whatever SomeProperty="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.PropertyOfViewModel}">
   </DataTemplate>
   ```